# System.xml to Enable/Disable module

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout

Could someone help me with the following issue I have with a module? I've been stuck for a couple of hours and could do with a fresh perspective.

I have two modules ModuleA and ModuleB which both extend the same Onepage_Checkout class using rewrites. I've almost solved the issue of the rewrite but I have run into two issues.

The first is that ModuleA and ModuleB both add a step to Onepage Checkout. Each additional step is visible but for some reason, ModuleB is skipped and doesn't become active.

The second is I need to add an option to disable or enable ModuleA per store/website

I've added this code to the system.xml file but it doesn't seem to work

```
<enable translate="label">
          <label>Enable</label>
          <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
          <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
          <sort_order>10</sort_order>
          <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
          <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
          <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        </enable>
```

Do I need to alter the DB table in any way or is there something else that I have missed?

Also, if I disable ModuleB for StoreA and disable ModuleA for storeB due to dependencies will they both still be active in either store? The reason I ask is I need to have the flexibility to enable or disable each module per store and not have them both active...

Can anyone assist? I really appreciate it...

Answer (score 4):

There is *no* connection between any config setting and your module *unless you evaluate that setting in PHP*.

Once upon a time there were two extensions which everyone installed on their Magento site: `Fooman_Speedster` and `Yoast_CanonicalUrl`. Both rewrote the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` class, so both authors had instructions on how to handle this. Because Yoast's extension loaded after Fooman's (Y > F), Yoast came up with a workaround which helped most people who were installing the extensions via Connect and had no ability to work with the code.

In *Yoast/CanonicalUrl/Block/Head*:

```
if (!(string)Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('Fooman_Speedster')->active == 'true')
{
  class Fooman_Speedster_Block_Page_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head{}
}
  class Yoast_CanonicalUrl_Block_Head extends Fooman_Speedster_Block_Page_Html_Head
{
     //Yoast's class definition...
}
```

This suggests an approach for you. You will need to read store-relative values though

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('[section]/[group]/enable')
```

and handle condition combinations where the other module is active or not.

Comment: Thanks for posting that, preemptive extension of a module you might have load beside yours, something I've been needing. And if you decide to remove the other module, it reverts... Which I was looking for.

Comment: The good old days before you could use Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Fooman_Speedster') to check for an active module